# Actions.refs.SCREEN_NAME doesn't work in react-native-router-flux package

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I can see this message Actions.refs is undefined;
I want to toggle menu in home screen in app.js where i defined routers.
so I have to call component's method but i can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how a router with react-native-router-flux look like :

```
const RouterComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="auth">
          <Scene
            initial
            key="autoLogin"
            component={AutoLoginPage}
            title="Please Login"
            hideNavBar={true}
            panHandlers={null}
          />
          <Scene
            key="login"
            component={LoginPage}
            title="Please Login"
            hideNavBar={true}
            panHandlers={null}
          />
        </Scene>
      </Scene>
    </Router>
```

You have to import the component you want to navigate to in your router file : in this exemple

```
import LoginPage from './scenes/LoginPage';
import AutoLoginPage from './scenes/AutoLoginPage';
```

Then, from your App.js, you just have to create the router component

```
import Router from './Router';

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
    return (
      <Provider store={store} >
        <Router />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Then you can do Actions.login() to be redirected to this page.
Be more precise about your problem if you want more informations. 
Hope it helps !

Comment: If there is login method in LoginPage Component then how can you call that method in AppComponent.